# wordpress woocommerce hide "out of stock" products category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It is easy to hide out of stock products in woocommerce, but how can I hide category from category menu that have only "out of stock" products?

Comment: This selected answer shows you how to hide it from the Category Widget which should point you in the right direction on how to hide it from whatever category menu you are talking about: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74896/woocommerce-product-category-widget-hide-categories-that-have-no-products-in-se-remove-product-and-product-category-from-url-struct

Comment: Which category menu you are talking about? navigation?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to your question?